# Class internal lambdas and boost function

Tags: c++, lambda, c++11, boost-function

I'm using C++0x's lambdas to define boost functions. I have some classes where I define some of their behaviour using lambdas/boost functions. What I was wondering is, is it possible to expose data about the classes into the lambda's context without altering the function definition? For example, I have a set of class like this:

```
class ConsumableItem : public Item
{
public:
    //Constructors here
    virtual bool Use(std::set<Character::BaseCharacter*> Users, std::set<Character::BaseCharacter*> Targets);
    virtual bool Use(std::set<Battles::BattleCharacter> Users, std::set<Battles::BattleCharacter> Targets, Battles::BattleField &field);
protected:
    bool UseRegularFunction;
    boost::function<void(std::set<Character::BaseCharacter*>, std::set<Character::BaseCharacter*>)> RegularUse;
    bool UseBattleFunction;
    boost::function<void(std::set<Battles::BattleCharacter>, std::set<Battles::BattleCharacter>, Battles::BattleField &)> BattleUse;
};

class StatBoostingItem : public ConsumableItem
{
public:
    StatBoostingItem(int UID, std::string &name, std::string &descript, boost::unordered_set<ItemFlags> Flags, boost::unordered_map<Stat, int> &boosts, int value);
protected:
    virtual bool Use(std::set<Character::BaseCharacter*> Users, std::set<Character::BaseCharacter*> Targets) override;
    virtual bool Use(std::set<Battles::BattleCharacter> Users, std::set<Battles::BattleCharacter> Targets, Battles::BattleField &field) override;
private:
    boost::unordered_map<Stat, int> StatBoosts;
}
```

And inside the constructor for stat boosting item, I'd like to be able to do this:

```
StatBoostingItem::StatBoostingItem(int UID, std::string &name, std::string &descript, boost::unordered_set<ItemFlags> Flags, boost::unordered_map<Stat, int> &boosts, int value)
    : ConsumableItem(UID, name, descript, Flags, ItemClass::STAT_BOOSTING_ITEM, value)
{
    StatBoosts = boosts;
    RegularUse = [](std::set<Character::BaseCharacter*> users, std::set<Character::BaseCharacter*> targets)
    {
        for (auto character = targets.begin(); character != targets.end(); ++character)
        {
            for (auto statBoost = StatBoosts.begin(); statBoost != StatBoosts.end(); ++statBoost)
            {
                //Item Effect in here
            }
        }
    };
}
```

This is more a curiosity thing as I know I can simply extend the boost::function definition to include a pointer to the item in question and get the data that way, or override my Use functions. But if I could somehow expose information into lambda about the class that contains it, that would be ideal as I'd be able to make use of it elsewhere as well

Comment: This is way too much boilerplate code for a simple example. Consider stripping it down to the very least that's needed to represent what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you need to access variables that are available in the scope of StatBoostingItem::StatBoostingItem from your lambda? In that case you could simply use [captures](http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/studio/composer/en-us/2009/compiler_c/cref_cls/common/cppref_lambda_lambdacapt.htm):

`RegularUse = [&](std::set<Character::BaseCharacter*> users, std::set<Character::BaseCharacter*> targets)`

The [&] tells the lambda to captures everything from the current scope by reference. If you need just a specific variable, you can capture just it, and you could also use [=] to capture everything by value. I guess you can also use [this] to capture a pointer to the Item instance:

`RegularUse = [this](std::set<Character::BaseCharacter*> users, std::set<Character::BaseCharacter*> targets)`

Didn't ever try that, but I see no reason why it shouldn't work. If it doesn't work (because `this` is somehow reserved, even though lambdas aren't methods), you can always work around it by assigning `this` to another variable and capturing it instead:

```
Item* item = this;
RegularUse = [item](std::set<Character::BaseCharacter*> users, std::set<Character::BaseCharacter*> targets)
{
    item.DoSomething();
}
```

Comment: @user127817 Be careful that a by-value default capture (`[=]`) implies `[this]` where applicable. So with `[=]` members of a class are actually captured by reference, not by value.